# How to convert EAN-13 bar code to EAN-8 bar code?

Tags: ean-13

It is easy to convert EAN-8 bar code to EAN-13 by adding zeros on left side of EAN-8 bar code... But I have a bar-code of EAN-13 type and i need to convert it to EAN-8?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow & Hope this helps!

1. Just trim that first 5 digits. Lossy Method
2. If you want to maintain a hash dictionary, then you can generate a new EAN-8 for EAN-13. This way without any loss of information, you can have 1 to 1 matching.

Comment: @Sampath can you provide some clear explanation. In case 1 what do we do for barcodes like 0855925266648?

Comment: In case of `0855925266648 `, remove the first 5 digits (`08559`) and you would get `25266648`. This generally comes under a lossy compression logic.